# set-title function in bash not work after applying powerline

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc

**set-title** ??

I just discover some trick that I use to change a bash-terminal title on the terminal. Here how it works :

```
#function set-title() on terminal

function set-title() {
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
  ORIG=$PS1
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
PS1=${ORIG}${TITLE}
}
```

I write that code in `~/.bashrc`. So I can change the title, and I not confused what terminal I use for.

**PRE PROBLEM**

I want to customize `bash` `vim` and their friend with the new look so I use this guy [guide](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/installing-powerline-as-quickly-as-possible/5381) to install powerline and it works perfectly.

**PROBLEM**

My `set title` function isn't working now.

**WHAT I TRY**

Make set-title code to the top of `.bashrc` not work. (I know this way is stupid)

Write that `set-title` on `usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh` not work, i think the code is different from `.bashrc`

So how to get my `set-title` function back?

Comment: how set title work?  I just write `set-title <your-title-here>` and the title text change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method (`"\[\e]2;$*\a\]"`) (outputs <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>Your title</kbd><kbd>^G(Bel)</kbd>). This is a "VT100 ESCape sequence" and is not correctly handled by ALL terminal emulators. Compare `echo $TERM` in both environments.

For a more portable approach, install and use `xttitle - Changes X terminal emulator window titles`. I have it built into my `~/.bashrc` (the `cd` command adjusts title):

```
# from the "xttitle(1)" man page - put info in window title
update_title()
{
    [[ $TERM = xterm ]] || [[ $TERM = xterm-color ]]  && xttitle "[$$] ${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:$PWD"
}

cd()
{
    [[ -z "$*" ]] && builtin cd $HOME
    [[ -n "$*" ]] && builtin cd "$*"
    update_title
}
```

Comment: So i should install the `xttitle` and write that code on `.bashrc` ? Ill try that.

Comment: Thanks thats work for me, if I may Ask again what `:$PWD` use for?

Comment: You may NOT ask a 2nd question. Users searching for "set-title function in bash not work after applying powerline" wouldn't find a `$PWD` answer, and would not be helped.